How do I use SSL and SASL for dovecot sieve autoreplies?
Dovecot's sieve can send its autoreplies via another SMTP server. But I can't find in the documentation anywhere how to configure authentication and certificates/ssl for this connection.
Currently my solution is to setup a secondary insecure mail server.
The config settings are set like so;
protocol lda {
    mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
    submission_host = smtp-02.mydomain.com:587
}


If I then try to add
    submission_ssl = yes

Dovecot will crash upon launching with Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/conf.d/50-sieve.conf line 20: Invalid value: yes
So while submission_ssl exists, the poor documentation doesn't specify how to actually use it. I assume that a private key, public cert , and CA cert are all needed, but there are only ssl_cert, ssl_key, and ssl_ca options, no submission_ssl_cert, etc.
There also don't appear to be any submission_sasl* options. Exactly how do I tell dovecot to supply username=admin, password=secure (example values, obviously) via SASL to the other mail server in order to send its autoreplies where the other mail server can then be configured for setting up DKIM signatures for this domain... Note; the 'other' mail server can simply be itself, but here too authentication requirement is a definitive yes.
Note: reason for authentication requirement; websites hosted on this server occasionally are compromised and authentication allows me to enforce limits on the quantity of spam that can be sent during such problems.
Alternatively, having some kind of setting to directly set/sign sieve-created mail with DKIM would also suffice.
Research
See the following topics;
https://dovecot.dovecot.narkive.com/woQrWTX0/vacation-message-and-dmarc-validation
https://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2012-November/069622.html
And (broken link, so...) https://web.archive.org/web/20140228153921/http://hg.dovecot.org/dovecot-2.1/file/e95479f439aa/doc/example-config/conf.d/15-lda.conf#l20
